# Need help for GLPaint adding a different twist to it

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, drawing

Can anyone point me to how I might modify the GLPaint program to put a tool like a pencil image on the screen and as I drag the image it actually draws the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLPaint is a particular bad starting point for this, because anything you draw to the screen becomes part of the painting. That would include the pencil. Changes required: Drawing operations performed on a off-screen FBO. Composition of off-screen FBO and drawing-tool pointer on the on-screen framebuffer.

On a side note: I'm getting annoyed by all those **"How can I make *GLPaint* do this and that?"** questions. GLPaint is an extremely bad example to start of OpenGL development. If you know OpenGL all those tasks could be done. But if you're an OpenGL newbie GLPaint is just the wrong starting point, because it doesn't explain why and how it works.

Please, if you want to learn OpenGL/-ES, don't start of OpenGL paint. Start with something simple, like drawing coloured triangles, so that you get an understanding how OpenGL works / not. Then take small steps.

Comment: Thank you for stating what's been on my mind for a while. Way too many people think they're going to create an iOS painting application just by taking the GLPaint code and tweaking it without understanding how it works. There are far too many questions here about this one example application: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=glpaint

Comment: Apparently, you and datenwolf have similar feelings about this and assume some things that just aren't true. I have spent time pouring over opengl es and examples, glpaint just being one example(albeit poor) and I am struggling, badly. I have so many books and pieces of source code I'm probably personally responsible for deforestation here in PA. Instead of complaining, why don't you "experts" write a good example with comments, since this comes up so many times. You could continue to complain or you could help those of us who continue to struggle.

Comment: @MichaelH. The amount of books you have doesn't matter. All you need is one well written tutorial. I recommend the one by Nicol Bolas http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Comment: @MichaelH. Yes it is. You need to understand all this stuff, to do something usefull with OpenGL. Chapters I, II, IV and V are relevant to your request – all their content. I and II tell you how do get things on the screen at all. IV gives you the insight how to implement different brushes, and chapter V contains the very information you need to draw in layers, like a image layer and a UI layer (for your pencil sprite).

Comment: @MichaelH - Tone is hard to communicate in short comments, and I didn't mean to imply laziness, only that OpenGL ES is a complex topic and people should start with something simpler than GLPaint. Apple's sample applications are notorious for being complicated, because they try to cram in many different APIs and technologies rather than simply focusing on one. You can see from that search I linked to just how many questions people have asked about this one example.

Comment: @MichaelH. - The lack of good OpenGL ES material is something I ran across, which is why I taught two classes on the topic. The videos of these classes (on both OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0) can be found for free on iTunes U as part of my iOS course: http://itunes.apple.com/us/course/advanced-iphone-development/id497193807 . That link is to a course for the new iTunes U iOS application. I go through the fundamentals of the topic in each of the ~3 hour sessions, and provide some simpler examples to illustrate the core concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Make an `UIImageView` object with your pencil image in it, and in `touchesBegan` you add it to the view, in `touchesMoved` you update the frame/center of that particular `UIImageView` object, and in `touchesCancelled` you remove the `UIImageView` object.

Comment: I think the OP wants to do it with OpenGL.